# Do the matrices representing Markov chains need to be square?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

I assume so — I ask in the context of defining an irreducible set. If a set is non-irreducible, you should be able to find a "smaller" Markov chain matrix nested within a larger one. That "smaller" chain matrix has to be square?

Comment: what do you means by a Markov chain to be a square? That the matrix representing the Markov chain is a square matrix?

Comment: Yes -- thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **yes**, because we account for the possibility of moving from any state to any state (and write a zero if this transition is not possible). This gives us $n \times n$ elements, which is a square matrix.